# Force vs. Momentum

Tags: forces, momentum

Obviously, if no external non-preservative force acts upon an object, if we apply a force to the object than the object will continue to hold that force within them. My question is, the object would have a constant acceleration. But as different times pass, the object would have changing momentum, since the it accelerates. Conservation of momentum states that the objects in play would have constant momentum in a closed system as long as only preservative forces work upon it. So if we say that the objects collide elastically, would that mean that the objects would collide and travel faster if we let the objects slide for a more time.

Comment: What's a "non-preservative" force? What do you mean "continue to hold that force within them"? If a 1kg mass is floating in space at original velocity 0, and a 1 newton force is exerted on it for a span of just 1 second, no longer, then at the end of that second its velocity is 1 meter per second, and at later times its velocity remains 1 meter per second.

Comment: Objects don't (individually) have constant momentum - only the vector sum of their respective momenta is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not all that clear to me, but I assume you are puzzled as to how momentum can be conserved whenever forces act on the individual bodies to accelerate such bodies.

First things first: if a force is exerted on a particular body, A, then it must be caused by a particular other body, B. By Newton's 3rd Law, A must also exert a force on B, a force of equal magnitude and opposing direction. These two forces form a Newton pair.

In a collision, A and B will exert forces on each that prevents the two bodies from going through one another, the forces acting in a manner as mentioned in the paragraph above. Now, note that for body A, the force exerted on it causes it to gain momentum. However, the force acting on B causes B to gain momentum of the same magnitude in the opposite direction. If you were to add up the momenta for A and B as vectors, they would sum to zero. And this is precisely what the conservation of linear momentum states:

Paraphrasing: The momentum of a closed system is conserved provided no external forces act.

To clarify, the momentum of the individual bodies will change in a collision, but the sum of the momenta of the two bodies will not (due to Newton's 3rd Law).

When you considered a closed  system to comprise of just A and B bodies, then the forces due to the collision are internal to the system (the bodies exerting and being exerted by such forces are inside of the system). Momentum of system is conserved.

If you consider a closed system comprising of just body A, the collision force acting on A is external to the system, as B, a body outside of the system, is exerting the force. Therefore, momentum of such a system is not conserved (external force present).

Special care in what your system contains is high recommended in the scenario.

PS Note that the fact a force is conservative or non-conservative does not matter in the slightest when it comes to the validity of Newton's 3rd Law or the Conservation of Linear Momentum. Whether a force is conservative only matters in terms of energy, which we need not deal with here.

Hope this helps!